# Query including the sum of one row in all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add in a column the sum of one of my columns and then show it for all of my rows. Specifically, I have a table where each row is a country, and there is a column identifying them with a region. A Third column is a measure. What I'm trying to do is sum the measures that are from the same region, and then show them for evert country.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT country, region, SUM(share) AS value_sum FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 GROUP BY region
```

I know that the group by makes it to appear just by region, but are those values resulting from the sum the ones that I want to place next to each country. Right now what I get is a table including the first country from every region and then the sum.

Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT country, region, SUM(share) AS value_sum FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 GROUP BY region, country` should work.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: It doesn't, if I group by both region and country, the sum that I get is not right, because it sums by region and country, and I only want the sum by region but I need it to appear repeatedly for every country within a region.

Comment: When you use any aggregate funtion (like SUM or COUNT) you MUST include every non-aggregate field that you select in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your `country` information is more specific than `region` information.

So you can wirte a main query to return two informations, `country` and `region`, and a subquery to return the sum about all countries in the same region.

Try this:

```
SELECT main.country, main.region,
    (SELECT SUM(sec.share)
    FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 sec WHERE sec.region = main.region) as total
FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 main
```

Answer (score 0):

You appears to want *correlation* `subquery` :

```
SELECT country, region, 
       (SELECT SUM(d1.share) 
        FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 d1
        WHERE d1.region = d.region
       ) AS value_sum 
FROM data_xlsx_Hoja2 d;
```

Comment: Is not correct add in group by a sub set of SELECT list field. mysql don't recognize this error. I advice you to remove the GROUP BY clause (or add country too)